# Apache rewrite rules: Read arguments dynamically

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wrote a small CMS for my own Websites.
I have the following rules in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?module=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?module=$1&controller=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?module=$1&controller=$2&action=$3 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?module=$1&controller=$2&action=$3&arg1=$4 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?module=$1&controller=$2&action=$3&arg1=$4&arg2=$5 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(.*)$ /index.php?module=$1&controller=$2&action=$3&arg1=$4&arg2=$5&arg3=$6 [L]
```

I need to read 6 GET arguments.
My code looks very redundant to me, but i dont know what i can do to shorten the code.
Somebody has a hint how i can read these 6 arguments with less lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amount of lines is really not going to hurt anything because in terms of amount of text that is nothing. The .htaccess file would have to be really big to have any noticeable performance concerns.

The way you have written your code there really isn't much you can do to reduce the lines because you need to match all URI's that may come in. That is why many CMS' including wordpress just routes everything to PHP in the `index.php` and then handle it there.

For example you can just do this one rule to route all requests

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Then get the URI in PHP using `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` and explode on `/` and get your pages or actions that way or however you want to handle it.

**That** is how you would shorten your lines in .htaccess

Comment: well, sadly nothing new here, but if thats the case, then answer accepted:-)